# JavaMail not working properly

Tags: jakarta-mail

Hi When i tried the below code in my home pc it is working fine.

```
 Properties props=new Properties();
   props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
   props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", 465);
   props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
   props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
   props.put("mail.smtp.port", 465);

  Session sess=Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
          protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
          return new PasswordAuthentication("user email ID","password");

          }
          });


  try{
     Message msg=new MimeMessage(sess); 
     msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("sunnykeerthi@gmail.com"));
     msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("sunnykeerthi@gmail.com"));
     msg.setSubject("Hi this is mail");
     msg.setText("Hi this is an email sent from java");
     Transport.send(msg);
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "message has been sent");

  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
  }
```

but when i tried the same in my office pc it is giving me the error as in the attached screen.
[image: Java Mail Errror o/p]
please help.

Comment: Error message is clear, you have *no access* to `smtp.gmail.com` from your office PC.

Comment: Hi RC thanks for the reply could you please tell me how do i access smtp,gmail.com? i am unaware of these concepts

Comment: You need to check with your company network admin.

Comment: hi buddy i got the server and port from my network admin. in the above code do i need to replace both the 465 ports?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your company is filtering the port 25?
Can you send a mail from a local desktop client (outlook, thunderbird...) when you set gmail as smtp?

Can you try setting your company smtp server in your java code?

Comment: we use ms exchange server for sending emails from outlook.

Comment: Point JavaMail at that server instead of gmail.  Note also this JavaMail FAQ item about [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) and this item about [debugging connection problems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).